# View Not getting updated with change in the object property

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this object `selectedTask` 2-way bound with [(ngModel)] to `<ion-select>` tag. However, when the changes are made to the value of fields in `selectedTask`, the Dom is not updated to reflect the change in value.

Here the html part:

```
<ion-label>Select Task</ion-label>
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTask" #A (ionChange)="updateChangedTask(false)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasklist" [value]="task">{{task.taskName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

the .ts file:

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef ...){ }

public selectedTask = {
  taskName: "",
  taskID: "" 
};

...

changeTask(task: any){
  this.selectedTask.taskName = task.taskName;
  this.selectedTask.taskID = task.taskID;
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

The value selected in the dropdown doesn't change when `changeTask()` is called. I know the reason - because the reference of `selectedTask` doesn't change and it is not detected by Angular by it as a change. How can I make it to detect the change in object field value?

Comment: Just to check, what are the properties for all `task` objects in `tasklist `? Is it only `taskName` and `taskID`?

Comment: @wentjun taskList contains list of all the tasks like: [ {taskName: "Grading", taskId: 01}, {taskName: "Teaching", taskId: 02},.... {taskName: "Away", taskId: 20}... etc]

Comment: Just to confirm, is `taskId` supposed to be a string or number? I notice you did not include the ' quotes '

Comment: @wentjun, they are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise you have binded an object to the `value` attribute. This is incorrect, as the value attribute only accepts numbers or strings.

However, if you want to bind an object to ion-option, you should use bind the `task` property to `ngValue` instead

```
<ion-label>Select Task</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTask" #A (ionChange)="updateChangedTask(false)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasklist" [ngValue]="task">{{task.taskName}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

---

If you would prefer to bind a string/number instead of an entire object, you will need to make the following changes to both your component.html, and component.ts

First, you bind `selectedTask` to the `taskID` string

```
public selectedTask: string = '';

changeTask(task: any){
  this.selectedTask = task.taskID;
}
```

And then, you bind the `value` attribute of ion-options to `task.taskID` which holds a string value.

```
<ion-label>Select Task</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTask" #A (ionChange)="updateChangedTask(false)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasklist" [value]="task.taskID">{{task.taskName}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

You can choose to adopt either methods, and 2-way data binding should work accordingly.

Comment: no this is not working. I can't still see the changes in the view.

Comment: @A.Ranjan when exactly is `changeTask` called? I realise I don't see it being used on either .html or on the .ts. Also, what are the properties for all `task` objects in `tasklist`? Are there anything else apart from the ID and Name?

Comment: sorry the file is too long. I extracted what I felt was necessary for brevity and simplicity. We have a button to assign task which calls changeTask.

Comment: @A.Ranjan this is 'interesting'.. Theoretically speaking this should be working since I am sure we have set the bindings right..  you can try calling adding that line with this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); on the changeTask method, but I doubt the outcome will change.. :/

Comment: thank you for your precious time @wentjun. I tried this too - https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html still not working. Has this to do anything with `ion-select`...?

Comment: well, I didn't know you had edited you answer. `If you would prefer to bind a string/number instead of an entire object` - Well, I gave binding to ID a try and it worked! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate, create new object. Instead of

```
  this.selectedTask.taskName = task.taskName;
  this.selectedTask.taskID = task.taskID;
```

do for example

```
 this.selectedTask = Object.assign({}, task);
```

Another take: use primitives (so, strings), instead of objects, for values.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTask" #A (ionChange)="updateChangedTask(false)">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasklist" [value]="task.taskID">{{task.taskName}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

and in TS:

```
public selectedTask = "";

//...

changeTask(task: any) {
  this.selectedTask = task.taskID;
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // may be unnecessary
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it looked great but unfortunately, the DOM is not updated. :/